# Cpp program to change the password of a linux user in /etc/shadow

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to make a program so that I can change a users password in linux. I have found out there are [putpwent](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putpwent.3.html) and [putspent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putspent.3.html) functions from <pwd.h> and <shadow.h>

I have came up with this but for some reason it does not work:

```
int main() {
    string username = "user";
    string password = "4321";

    struct passwd *pw = getpwnam(username.c_str());
    struct spwd *sp = getspnam(username.c_str());

    if (pw == NULL || sp == NULL) {
        cerr << "Failed to get user information." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char *encrypted_password = crypt(password.c_str(), sp->sp_pwdp);

    pw->pw_passwd = encrypted_password;

    if (putpwent(pw, stdout) != 0) {
        cerr << "Failed to update password." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (putspent(sp, stdout) != 0) {
        cerr << "Failed to update shadow file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the execution of the code goes through but the password is not changed. This is the output of the code

NEW PASSWORD:        `user:$6$jhci4oxH6C4h9off$AwzsRAjJUh21Sf2DY7ktY5KdNbYG3YhsdjTshU8FanJF/pfqRcq8jiR6Jvq/cbubiMbTO50HU7w79Tx2DQnwq/:1001:1001::/home/user:/bin/bash`

OLD PASWORD  (does not get modified in /etc/shaddow) `user:$6$jhci4oxH6C4h9off$.SEwXqgYa1Un5t8rTdVCccicmk3sxLW5NPMqiSdBNcGBNX.pO404Cuic8Wdv7N4IhNVl3KmhtiKunUbjBQq3U0:19515:0:99999:7:::`

does anyone has some guidelines on how to do this?

changing a linux user password with a cpp program

Comment: What does `errno` tell you?  (Check it after each failed call.)

Comment: @blitzmo – 
You could bother to look which of `getpwnam` and `getspnam` fails. As which user did you run?

Comment: Yes, probably need to run this as root (check the docs)

Comment: I am running the program as root and the permissions are root also

Comment: I did play around with the permissions a bit. and now I pass that step but the password is not changing to the new pass

Comment: _"the password is not changing to the new pass"_, how could it be if you're writing the entry to the standard output stream? Shouldn't you open the files `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` and pass those as argument to the related functions?

Comment: @ErdalKüçük That was my first option to just write to the file. But I've found online that I do not need to with `putpwent` and `putspent`

Comment: Ah, ok., i didn't know that. But if you look up some examples, they all open those files, e.g. https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/putpwent/cpp-putpwent-function-examples.html or https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/putspent/cpp-putspent-function-examples.html.

Answer (score 0):

In general, on Linux, most failing library calls (probably including [putpwent(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putpwent.3.html) ...) are, on failure, setting the [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).
So you need to `#include <errno.h>`  and you could use [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) (which needs `<stdio.h>`).

The management of password files is  reserved to root running processes. A possibility is to configure suitably, then use the [sudo(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html) utility. For exemple thru `system(3)`  using explicitly `/usr/bin/sudo`

If you want to avoid any external commands, you may open a security hole (by mistake) in your system.

#### the `sudo` utility is using the (very tricky) [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) machinery.

If you want to reproduce it (be **very careful** and have your C++ code checked by some human linux expert) you would need to code a setuid executable and use carefully [setuid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) and [seteuid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html). **this is tricky** so take a few days to read several books about it.

Of course, you need to be authorized (by the owner or authority of that Linux system) to do so.

#### I suggest to download the source code of `sudo` and study that code carefully.

Once you trust your ELF executable, use the [chmod(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) command to set uid that executable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead; to make it work, you must enter a legitimate username. and in the Linux system, you need permissions to change the password. If not used carefully, the system() function can pose a security risk.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    std::string username;
    std::string password;

    std::cout << "Enter the username: ";
    std::cin >> username;
    std::cout << "Enter the new password: ";
    std::cin >> password;

    std::string command = "echo ";
    command += username + ":" + password + " | chpasswd";

    int result = system(command.c_str());

    if (result == 0) {
        std::cout << "Password change successful." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Password change failed." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I already know that it works with system(). I was more interested in the libraries mentioned.